# Presenting a full-screen view that hides the status bar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, statusbar

I have a view controller that I present full-screen using the presentViewController method. The presenting view controller shows the status bar, and the presented view controller does not. The issue is that when the new view controller fades in on top, the bottom view controller is shown animating the status bar out by sliding up. Is there any way to not do this? preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation is not implemented on either view controller, so I thought it should default to fading out.

Comment: I don't think so. Each view controller is showing/not showing the status bar as expected, but I want it to not do that sliding animation.

Comment: You're right. So you want the status bar to not animate up when the view controller is presented, just be covered by the presented view controller?

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do about that. I believe the status bar is actually in its own window, since UIWindow has [UIWindowLevelStatusBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIWindowLevel) as a possible window level.